# Arc'd jumping method?

Tags: java

Okay, so I'm making a platformer, and I wanna know how I can make a arc'd jump easily. Like what Mario does in super Mario Bros 1. Any ideas on a simple way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Simulate gravity ^^

you mario will have a delta to control its move on X, then make it 2D vect that will include a Y componnent this Y will always have a -gravity add to the vertical acceleration.

this way when your jumping you'll have the forward the jumping force+the gravity that will progressively drag mario back down giving you your arc

Comment: "Simulate gravity" made me smile.

Comment: it makes me smile too ^^ but it sounded just too perfect as an answer :p

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple pseudo code:

```
if playerHitsGround or playerHitsBlockAbove:
   playerGravity = 0 // reset the gravity
endif

if jumpButtonHit and playerGravitiy == 0:
    playerGravity = -5 // set the "negative" gravity
endif

playerGravity += 0.1 // increase the gravity, so we fall back
playerPositionY += playerGravity // apply our "gravity" to the player
```

That's as simple as you can get, and most likely also the same method that was used back in the NES days. The "arc" here comes from the fact that while the "gravity" is being applied, you also move forward.